# 2 массива ключевых слов проверить на пересечение!

Tags: php

помогите написать функцию на php. Есть темы (рубрики) и у них есть ключевые слова.Есть статьи и у них тоже есть ключевые слова, и надо проверить создать 2 массива ключевых слов, и эти массивы проверить на пересечение,если ключевые слова в 2 массивах пересекаются больше 50%, то данный документ относить к данной  рубрике!
Код!

```
$Pers = query("SELECT * FROM publ_cat WHERE ($Where $Where_Back) AND resource_type = '$Type_Liter' AND (document_type !='13' AND document_type !='14')"); 
if (num_rows($Pers) != 0){ 
  $OK = 'Y'; 
  while($row_publ = fetch_array($Pers)){ 
    if(ifSelect($row_publ['keywords'], $TemasCond)){ 
      //todo: здесь написать функцию
      $List_ID[$row_publ['link_id']] = $row_publ['id'];
      $List_BIB[$row_publ['link_id']] = $row_publ['bib_description'];
      $List_TEXT[$row_publ['link_id']] = preg_replace("[||\s]","",$List_BIB[$row_publ['link_id']]); 
      $List_Col[$row_publ['link_id']] = 77; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Если бы были просто 2 массива php, то я предложил бы по очереди пробежаться по каждому из них и в третьем массиве увеличить на 1 ячейку с словом из массива. потом посмотреть соотношения общего кол-ва слов, к кол-ву слов в этом массиве со значением 2 (это те слова, что оказались в обоих массивах). Но по вашему коду вообще не ясно что где. И учитывая, что как минимум половина у вас в БД, то может и вторая половина то же в базе - и тогда эту задачу надо решать прямо в базе, одним sql-запросом